# Changing the order of columns in a list view - Powershell

Tags: list, powershell, view

I am trying to add a new column called "REF" to all existing views using powershell which I have succeeded in doing, however when adding the column it is automatically added to the end of the array making it last in the view, I need it to be at the beggining [0]

Can I add the column in at point [0] forcing the other columns to move down the array possibly like this?

```
$view.ViewFields[0].Add($refField)
```

Or would I need to copy out the array and re add it in the new order?

```
$originalArray = $view.ViewFields    
$view.ViewFields.Add($refField)
$view.ViewFields.Add($originalArray[0])
$view.ViewFields.Add($originalArray[1])
$view.ViewFields.Add($originalArray[2])
```

What is the best approach?

Thanks,

Colin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do the following to reorder fields in wild lists:

- Create an array of the fields order (Or spreadsheet/xml file I use spreadsheets)
- Delete the viewfields with SPView.ViewFields.DeleteAll()
- Loop through the array for the order you want (or spreadsheet which is what I use) and add the field in question SPView.ViewFields.Add(FieldName);
- SPView.Update()
- library/list.Update()

I use this as a reusable script, and I find it is the best approach (Similar to what you have already done)

Comment: Rather than using XML / spreadsheet can I get the code to save the current order and then readd them, I'm not sure what type of object to use to achieve this? I thought the below but it doesnt seem to work...

$originalViewFields1 = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList
$originalViewFields = $view.ViewFields

Comment: SPViewFieldCollection, is basically a StringCollection. So it should be "New-Object System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection"

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Hugh Wood answerm, I could made this quick and dirty solution.

You can copy and past you wanted order in $order (even from excel sheet) and so get simply the requested order. Please be aware there is no logical check:

```
Add-PsSnapin Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell
$web = get-spweb https://sharepoint/sites/site
$list = $web.lists["yourListName"]
$view = $list.views["Main View"]
$orginalViewFields = $view.ViewFields
$view.ViewFields.DeleteAll()
$order="field1
field2
field3"
$order.Split([Environment]::NewLine) | where { -not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_) } | % 
{
   $view.ViewFields.Add($field) 
}
$view.Update()
```